# Compatibility of Yetter-Drinfeld modules.

Tags: modules, representation-theory, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

Let $H$ be a Hopf algebra. A Yetter-Drinfeld module over $H$ is a triple $(V, \cdot, \delta)$, where $\cdot : H \otimes V \to V$ , $\delta : V \to H \otimes V$
are actions and coactions respectively, $(V, \cdot)$ is an H-module, $(V, \delta)$ is an H-comodule, and
\begin{align}
\delta(h \cdot v) = h_{(1)}v_{(-1)}S(h_{(3)}) \otimes h_{(2)} \cdot v_{(0)} \quad (1)
\end{align}
for all $v \in V$, $h \in H$, where $\delta(v)=v_{(-1)} \otimes v_{(0)}$, $(\Delta\otimes 1)(\Delta(h))=h_{(1)}\otimes h_{(2)} \otimes h_{(3)}$.

I am trying to understand the compatibility condition (1). Where do the compatibility condition (1) come from? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242280/compatibility-conditions-for-yetter-drinfeld-modules?rq=1) there is a proof of equivalence of two definitions of Yetter-Drinfeld modules. Defining Yetter-Drinfeld modules on Hopf algebra using antipodal map $S$ is more natural, because there is a lot of properties of Yetter-Drinfeld modules related to properties of $S$ - for example [in this article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405005.pdf) you can find some of them.